# Where/how to get the Mac OSX "login" command

Tags: macos, bash, unix, authentication

To make a long story short, my terminal was not working so a forum said to delete the "login" command in /usr/bin. It worked. Now, a month later, I am trying to install fink, and it is not working because it cannot find the "login" command.

No backup disks (grrr)
The install disk is not working (I hold down "C" and it logs me in anyway)

So, I was wondering if there was somewhere I could download the unix executable or--since mac is not open source, download the source code for the login command and compile it. It would have to work on my mac (10.5.8) so I really do not know where to start.

Comment: Now you know not to delete things randomly just because someone on a forum said to.

Comment: For the record, this was from one of apple's forums and it did work. But yes, I must be more careful.

Comment: This really isn't a programming-related question. Try superuser.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"mac is not open source" is not accurate. Portions of Mac OS X are open source and the source code is available at http://opensource.apple.com. Specifically, `login` for Mac OS 10.5.8 is available at http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/system_cmds/system_cmds-433.8/login.tproj.

That being said, compiling system components is not really trivial, even with help from [DarwinBuild](http://darwinbuild.macosforge.org/). I would say your best shot is to grab a copy of the installation media. Have you tried contacting Apple (Store) support?

Comment: Thanks for the advise. No I haven't contacted the apple store yet. I am pretty sure it is going to be "set up an appointment" and it's about 40 minutes away--so I am trying to fix it myself before I head over there.