# How to delete an unfinished Darwinbuild build

Tags: macos, memory, restore, disk

I got darwinbuild off macports to get a single unix executable (long story, see [Where/how to get the Mac OSX "login" command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579745/where-how-to-get-the-mac-osx-login-command)). I was having trouble figuring out how it worked, so I tried their website's example build, "darwinbuild xnu"

It worked, and when I opened the new volume it mounted in finder, it appeared to be building a whole new mac osx (I know this is probably not the case, but that is what it looked like to me at least.) So I grabbed the binary I wanted, hit control-c in terminal, and unmounted the volume. Everything seemed to work out, but even after restarting the computer, I could not get the 2gig or so that build/mount/kernal/thing took up.

I even tried restoring a timemachine backup, but even that would not bring the free space back.

So how do I get rid of this thing once and for all?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the location the files were written to, navigate there in Finder then delete them. If you don't, read the documentation that comes with the Darwin stuff you downloaded (it'll be there, believe me) to find out or download a drive space analyzer app to locate it.

Really, I don't see how these questions are about programming? They're more "how do I fix something I screwed up ancillary to programming-related efforts," which are of course superuser.com material.